# How to use old database in lokijs?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, lokijs

I am using framework7 with lokijs.
To use lokijs database, i need to create new database everytime with new loki(dbname)

how do i create a database on my first run and from next runs just load that database ?

Answer (score 1):

To create new database (each run this code will clear your data in file mydb.json):

```
var loki = require('lokijs');
var db = new loki('mydb.json');
var users = db.addCollection('users');//create users collection in file mydb.json
db.saveDatabase();//save file
```

To work with file

```
var loki = require('lokijs');
var db = new loki('mydb.json);
var users = db.getCollection('users');
users.insert({name: 'User', age: 20}); //add user with name User and age 20
users.removeWhere({age: 20}); //delete all users where age = 20
//something else
db.saveDatabase(); //save changes to file
```

also you can read [docs](http://lokijs.org/#/docs)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [wiki](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/wiki/LokiJS-persistence-and-adapters) is a good place to start for your issue. LokiJS can load an existing database with the `loadDatabase()` method.

Comment: thanks i got it working now using adapter and loadDatabase function :)